# Return mysql fetch data and insert into form field value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a list of clients on a page, each client has an icon to click on to edit the client details.

```
<i class="fas fa-user-edit gray openModal" data-modal="modal2" client="'.$client['id'].'"></i>
```

Everything is good up to this point.  click the icon the proper modal opens and it triggers the js file just fine.  (I did alot of console logs to ensure).  The client variable in my jquery file holds fine and i'm able to get it passed to the php file.

in the php file i'm able to pull the information into an array and i was able to just echo the $client['firstName'] and have it show in the console.

when i moved to getting that information and parse it as the Json is when i got lost. Can someone please help me take my result and load into my form fields. The code i have now may be totally off because i've been playing with different code from different searches.

form (shortened to two fields for ease of example)

```
<form id="form" class="editClient ajax" action="ajax/processForm.php" 
method="post">

<input type="hidden" id="refreshUrl" value="? 
page=clients&action=view&client=<?php echo $client['id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="client" value="<?php echo $client['id'];?>">

<div class="title">
    Client Name             
</div>



<div class="row">

    <!-- first name -->
    <div class="inline">
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $client['firstName']; ?>" autocomplete="nope" required>
        <br>
        <label for="firstName">First Name<span>*</span></label>
    </div>
<!-- last  name -->
    <div class="inline">
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $client['lastName']; ?>" autocomplete="nope" required>
        <br>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name<span>*</span></label>
    </div>

</form>
```

javascript/jquery file

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function() {

  //$('body, html, div').scrollTop(0);

  var that = $(this),
  client = that.attr('client');

  $.ajax({

    type: "post",
    url: "ajax/getClient.php",
    data: {id:client},
    success: function(response){

      var result = JSON.parse(response);
      var data = result.rows;

      $("#firstName").val(data[0]);

    }
  })

  });
```

php file

```
<?php

include('../functions.php');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id="'.$_POST['id'].'"';
$result = query($sql);
confirmQuery($result);

$data = fetchArray($result);

echo json_encode(['response' => $data, 'response' => true]);
```

?>

UPDATED ----------

Here is my final js file that allowed my form values to be set.

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function() {



var that = $(this),
        client = that.attr('client');

        $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: "ajax/getClient.php",
            data: {id:client},
            success: function(response){

            var result = JSON.parse(response);


                    $("select#primaryContact").append( $("<option>")
                    .val(result[0].primaryContact)
                        .html(result[0].primaryContact)
                    );
                $("select#primaryContact").append( $("<option>")
                    .val("")
                        .html("")
                    );
                if (result[0].email !== "") {
                    $("select#primaryContact").append( $("<option>")
                    .val(result[0].email)
                        .html(result[0].email)
                    );
                }
                if (result[0].phoneCell !== "") {
                    $("select#primaryContact").append( $("<option>")
                    .val(result[0].phoneCell)
                        .html(result[0].phoneCell)
                    );
                }
                    if (result[0].phoneHome !== "") {
                    $("select#primaryContact").append( $("<option>")
                    .val(result[0].phoneHome)
                        .html(result[0].phoneHome)
                    );
                }



                     $("input#firstName").val(result[0].firstName);
                     $("input#lastName").val(result[0].lastName);
                     $("input#address").val(result[0].address);
                     $("input#city").val(result[0].city);
                     $("input#zip").val(result[0].zip);
                     $("input#email").val(result[0].email);
                     $("input#phoneCell").val(result[0].phoneCell);
                     $("input#phoneHome").val(result[0].phoneHome);
                     $("input#phoneFax").val(result[0].phoneFax);
                     $("input#source").val(result[0].source);
                     $("input#referBy").val(result[0].referBy);
                     $("input#client").val(result[0].id);

        }



        })

        });
```

Comment: `echo json_encode(['response' => $data, 'response' => true]);` results in the following JSON ... `{"response":true}` because an "object" keys are unique, so the second one is "overwriting" the first

Comment: ok, so i removed the second one and I am now getting the array.  ive tried to console log just one result from the array, but i guess i'm clueless on that.  console.log(data[4]);  or am i way off?

Comment: it's not an array ... you'd be getting `{"response":$data}` ... so `function(response){` response here is `{"response":$data}` and `var result = JSON.parse(response);` result here is `{response:$data}` so `var data = result.rows;` there is nothing called `rows` at this level ... it'd be `result.response.rows` perhaps - of course, you could figure this out by `console.log(response)` and checking the output

Comment: this is the part im not understanding....i change my var data to result.response.rows and now i get this error - getclient.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined.   i don't understand how to retrieve the data when i console log response.  i see it all     [{"4":"Aaron","firstName":"Aaron","5":"Henry","lastName":"Henry""}]

Comment: so `result[0]` will be the object `{4:"Aaron", firstName: "Aaron", 5: "Henry", lastName: "Henry"}` I guess

Comment: i guess i'm not understanding...i've tried to log a result and get nothing......

Comment: also confused as to why there are two results for each field....

Comment: that would be the PHP side of things, I'm afraid I can't help you there

Comment: thanks for the help....i was able to reread what you said and play around some more with some searches and got it to work.  thank you!  i updated with what i ended up with